# Multidimensional flexible array initializer in C

Tags: c, arrays

Is there any way to replace the [5] in the array declaration by [] ? Everything is declared statically, so why does it need to know the size ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int M[][5]={
        {0,  1, 2, 3, 4},
        {10,11,12,13,14},
        {20,21,22,23,24},
        {30,31,32,33,34},
    };

    int DimX=sizeof(M)/sizeof(M[0]);    // 4
    int DimY=sizeof(M[0])/sizeof(int);  // 5

    printf("Size: %d %d\n", DimX, DimY);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In a word, no. To determine the index of an N dimensional array element you need to know all but the first array dimension.

Comment: Why didn't they fix that in the last standard? I really don't see any reason this should be so except of course the age of the language...

Comment: @Dr.Nefario: how would you expect the compiler to infer the array dimensions ?

Comment: @Paul R Well... Since the compiler has to parse the code maybe parsing the entire array definition and then allocate the space, isn't that possible? Could you please provide a link on the topic?

Comment: Expressions that compute using `sizeof` (which, btw, *is not a function*) should be of type `size_t`, not `int`.

Comment: @Dr.Nefario: initializers are not mandatory, and may also be incomplete, so you can not in general use them to infer all of the array dimensions.

Comment: This restriction is there to make pointer arithmetic easy. as @PaulR suggested initializers are just optional and since all kinds of arrays are stored linearly in memory, so to make compiler's job easier, its necessary to mention all dimentions of a matrix but first.